# Simpler proof that the coefficients must be proportional for an equation involving a ratio of two linear polynomials?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm an adult learner, but I have recently been doing some math olympiad preparation problems to bone up my algebra--it has been a lot of fun!

Recently I came across a problem that involved something like

$$\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}=\frac{ex+f}{gx+h} $$

The problem only involved a specific case, and I was able to solve it a couple different ways, but I started to get curious about the possibility that if this expression is true for all x (where defined) that 
$$\frac{a}{e}=\frac{b}{f}=\frac{c}{g}=\frac{d}{h}$$

I was able to persuade myself of that, because if $x=0$ we immediately have $\frac{b}{d}=\frac{f}{h}$ and so $\frac{b}{f}=\frac{d}{h}$. And if we consider $\lim_{x \to \infty}$ we have $\frac{a}{c}=\frac{e}{g}$ and so $\frac{a}{e}=\frac{c}{g}$. Also, the zeros of both sides, when defined, demand $ax+b=ex+f$ and so $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{e}{f}$ and $\frac{a}{e}=\frac{b}{f}$ (and where the zeros aren't defined, we have constant ratios, so we're done).

I have a hunch, though, that I am somehow radically overcomplicating this--does anyone know off hand if there is a (potentially much) simpler way?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Möbius_transformation#Projective_matrix_representations

Comment: Thank you for the reference! It has been interesting reading, but the connection is a bit above my level. Can you elaborate slightly?

Answer (score 1):

good question and welcome to the platform.

I haven't fully worked it out, but this might push you in the right direction..

Given,
$$\frac{ax+b}{cx+d} = \frac{ex+f}{gx+h}$$

multiply out to get
$$agx^2 + ahx + bgx + bh = cex^2 + cfx + dex + df.$$

For these to have any chance of being equal, we must have $agx^2 = cex^2$. This implies $ag = ce \rightarrow \frac{a}{e} = \frac{c}{g}$. Similarly, we must have $bh = df \rightarrow \frac{b}{f} = \frac{d}{h}$.

Then you have to equate $\frac{a}{e} = \frac{c}{g}$ and $\frac{b}{f} = \frac{d}{h}$ some way.

Comment: Thank you for the warm welcome!